# Why $p\{N>n\}=p\{X_1+...+X_n\leq x\}$.

Tags: probability

Let $(X_k)$ a sequence iid of random variable uniform on $[0,1]$. Let $x\in]0,1[$ and $N=\min\{n\geq 1\mid X_1+...+X_n>x\}$. Why

$$p\{N>n\}=p\{X_1+...+X_n\leq x\}  \ \ ?$$

Comment: If $N>n$, then $X_1 + \cdots + X_n \le x$, as $N$ is the smallest $n$ for which $X_1 + \cdots + X_n > x$. Conversely, if $X_1 + \cdots + X_n \le x$, then $n < N$, again by the definition of $N$. This shows equality of events $$\{N > n\} = \{X_1 + \cdots + X_n \le n\}$$

Comment: The sets are equal. It might help to call $S_n(\omega)=X_1(\omega)+\cdots X_(\omega)$. You only need that $(S_n(\omega))_n$ is increasing for each $\omega$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Observe that **$N$ is the minimum positive integer such that**
  $$
  X_1 + \cdots + X_N > x
  $$
  Thus 
  $$N > n \implies X_1 + \cdots + X_n \leq x$$
- Conversely, if
  $$
  X_1 + \cdots + X_n \leq x
  $$
  then of course
  $$
  X_1 + \cdots + X_n \leq x \implies N > n
  $$
- **Conclusion**: $\{X_1 + \cdots + X_n \leq x\}$ is equivalent to $\{N > n\}$.
  Thus their probability should be same.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $N = N(\omega)$ satisfies
$$(X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_{N-1})(\omega) \leq x \text{ and } (X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_N)(\omega) > x$$

Therefore $N = N(\omega) > n$ if and only if
$$(X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_n)(\omega) \leq (X_1 + X_2 + \ldots + X_{N-1})(\omega) \leq x$$